# Main difference between metadata and vardefs

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

It seems simple, but I'm not sure I understand the difference. Both metadata files and vardefs contain field definitions and both ultimately point to Sugarfields

So what it's the difference between the 2 when it comes to field definitions?

Comment: So I'm clear on your meaning, can you give an example (preferably with code) as to the metadata you're speaking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference betwene metadata and vardefs is,
metadata is a simple table structure definition so sugarcrm knows what fields/tables to add to the database on repair&rebuild.

Vardefs are field-definitions inside modules, also resulting in db fields in the table of the module, but vardefs can't exist without a module, metadata can (only) exist without a module.